# exportLinks missing in files.list() and files.get() in google drive API for google document

Tags: node.js, api, oauth, google-drive-api

When obtaining a [`File` resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files), and that file is a Google document, that file is supposed to have an `exportLinks` object.

When I do this from my NodeJs client, I do get a file with many of the fields, but `exportLinks` is missing. When I used the [Try It!](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it) section in their documentation, `exportLinks` is indeed present, for the same file. The only discernible difference is that my request uses an `Authorization` header, whereas the "Try it" section appears to use a `key` query param.

When do `exportLinks` get dropped?

---

More details:

Am using [`google-auth`](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs) and [`googleapis`](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) to issue my requests, and other APIs I am calling appears to work fine.

Also considered that it was a scope-permissions thing, and tried using the broadest scope for google drive - `https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client` - however this made no difference.

Answer (score 4):

You are right that this is occurring because you aren't using a permissive enough scope. Make sure you are using the right scope though. What you pasted above is wrong. In my testing, I did not get exportLinks when I used the 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly' scope, but when I added the full scope ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'), I was able to get the exportLinks as expected.